# Generating an OAuth2 token from user logged in via Windows Credentials (Kerberos)

Tags: wcf, oauth-2.0, spnego

We are running an application via Remote Desktop Services. The application authenticates to our web api middleware running in under WCF using `Negotiate` and Windows Auth.

We now have a scenario where the middleware needs to make calls to another service and pass a bearer token so that it can run as the user who made the initial request. It would also enable us to not have to use `Negotiate` on every request, which is fairly expensive.

We're looking for a way that we can make a OAUTH  `grant_type = client_credentials`, but using the credentials of the user which is authenticated via `Negotiate` to our middleware. I haven't seen any examples of how that would be done. All of the examples I see pass the users credentials via client_id and client_secret, or in the HTTP Basic Auth header, but no examples of `grant_type = client_credentials`, where the credentials are via `Negotiate`.

Answer (score 0):

Getting a token as the user without the user interactively logging in via OAuth is generally not supported since the password is unknown.

Aim for option 1 below:

1. Use client credentials, then pass the user id in addition via a different parameter, such as a path segment - simplest option is to get the downstream service to support this
2. Login via OAuth and federate to an Identity Provider that uses windows auth - this is likely to be a very big migration job - though it is the preferred way to use OAuth with Windows auth

Comment: I'm not clear how option 1 would work? What is "path segment"? Can you give an example of what the full request cycle might look like? I'm also not sure that I've been clear. The user is already authenticated to Windows using kerberos, i.e. they have logged into a Windows Desktop via Remote Desktop Services.

Our application, uses WinHTTP to make a call to a service which supports Kerberos authentication via Negotiate. What we would like to do is to be able to use the Kerberos authentication to then produce a client_credentials token.

Comment: You will need to configure a client ID and client secret to get the token. But there is no way to get the user id into the token - so you will need to supply the user id in addition to the token when you call the downstream service. If you were getting the address for the user this might be a call such as GET /users/123/address for user 123. And of course you need to send a user id that the service understands.